# VBScript To Launch Internet Explorer With A URL Generated

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, scripting, hta

Currently I'm a learning HTA programming.  I have a requirement as follows.

There are two input boxes in the form (both are mandatory).  When I enter the values and click on search button, a url would be created based on the inputs.  The should launch the Internet Explorer application with the generated url.

My issue is that I'm able to launch IE browser but I'm not able to pass the url to it.
I have tried many ways but I'm not able to get it done.

I have the given my code below.  I have removed my erroneous syntax of passing the url to the browser.  The below code would create the url and launch a blank IE explorer.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script language="VBScript"> 

    Sub RunProgram
        callb = document.getElementById("callb").value
        call = document.getElementById("call").value
        url = "www.google.com"&callb&"and"&call
        msgbox(url)
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run "iexplore.exe"
    End Sub

</script> 
</head> 
<body>

<form style="width:254px; height:44px;">
CallB: <input type="text" id="callb" value=""><br>
Call  : <input type="text" id="call" value=""><br><br>
<button onclick="RunProgram">search</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load a URL in the default browser by using the Run() method of WShell:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "www.google.com"
```

If you want to explicitly load the URL in Internet Explorer, you'll need to determine the full path to IEXPLORE.EXE first, then pass it to Run():

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """" & strExePath & """ www.google.com"
```

Or

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """" & strExePath & """ " & strURL
```

Note the quotes. You'll want to put quotes around the path to IE in case the path contains a space. In order to specify a quote within a string, you have to double it. If the quotes are confusing, you can use Chr(34) to specify a quote character:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Chr(34) & strExePath & Chr(34) & " " & strURL
```

Comment: You are really great.  Its working for me. I have a small concern.  Could you please explain a little clearly about the quotes in the syntax?

Comment: Sure. When you type a path at the command line, you must use quotes if the path contains spaces. For example, "C:\Program Files". The same rule applies to the Run() function. To specify a quote within a string it must be doubled. That's why we use 4 quotes. One to start the string, a double-quote, and then another quote to end the string. Alternatively, you can use Chr(34) to specify a quote. I've edited my answer to show this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier, i usually use this function to add the double quotes in a variable.

```
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

An example showing you how it is easy to use it.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,ws,DossierProgramfiles,Winrar,FileZilla,FireFox
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DossierProgramfiles = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PROGRAMFILES%")
Winrar = DblQuote(DossierProgramfiles & "\Winrar\Winrar.exe")
If fso.FileExists(DossierProgramfiles & "\Winrar\Winrar.exe") Then
    MsgBox Winrar,Vbinformation,Winrar
    ws.run Winrar
Else
    MsgBox "Le fichier " & Winrar & " n'existe pas",VbCritical,"Le fichier " & Winrar & " n'existe pas"
End If
FileZilla = DblQuote(DossierProgramfiles & "\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe")
If fso.FileExists(DossierProgramfiles & "\FileZilla FTP Client\filezilla.exe") Then
    MsgBox FileZilla,Vbinformation,FileZilla
    Ws.run FileZilla
Else
    MsgBox "Le fichier " & FileZilla & " n'existe pas",VbCritical,"Le fichier " & FileZilla & " n'existe pas"
End If
FireFox = DblQuote(DossierProgramfiles & "\Mozilla Firefox\FireFox.exe")
If fso.FileExists(DossierProgramfiles & "\Mozilla Firefox\FireFox.exe") Then
    MsgBox FireFox,Vbinformation,FireFox
    ws.run FireFox
Else
    MsgBox "Le fichier " & FireFox & " n'existe pas",VbCritical,"Le fichier " & FireFox & " n'existe pas"
End If
'****************************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'****************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with this HTA :

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Search on Google with Internet Explorer"
BORDER="THIN"
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
ICON="magnify.exe"
INNERBORDER="NO"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
SCROLL="NO"
SELECTION="NO"
SYSMENU="YES"
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<script language="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Dim Titre
Titre = "Search on Google with Internet Explorer"
Self.document.title = Titre
Sub window_onload()
    CALL CenterWindow(300,180)
    Self.document.bgColor = "Orange"
End Sub
Sub RunProgram()
    Dim X,Y,URL,objShell,Param,MaCmd
    X = text1.value
    Y = text2.value
    Param = "#q="& X & "+" & Y &""
    URL = "www.google.com"& Param
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    msgbox("iexplore.exe " & DblQuote(URL)),VbInformation,Titre
    MaCmd = "iexplore.exe "& DblQuote(URL) &""
    objShell.Run(MaCmd)
End Sub
'***************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***************************************************
'Position Windows
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft, itop
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body><center>
Text1 : <input type="text" id="text1" Name="text1" value="Hackoo"><br>
Text2 : <input type="text" id="text2" Name="text2" value="Vbscript+HTA"><br><br>
<input type="submit" Value="Search on Google" onclick="RunProgram()"></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet would launch this url in the default browser.

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run url`

Answer (score -1):

How about this

This is a VBS script

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With objExplorer
        .Navigate strPath
        .ToolBar = 1
        .StatusBar = 1
        .Width = 1000
        .Height = 593 
        .Left = 1
        .Top = 1
        .Visible = 1
        .Navigate("https://www.google.com")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**